# Book with alien POV

Tags: story-identification

A few years back, I found a book in the library. It was in the English section so I presume it was never translated into Serbian, which is my mother language. I also remember it had colorful covers and it looked so beat down and so old that it has to be from at least '70 or '80.

As for the plot I remember the following:

1. It was from an alien perspective
2. The main protagonist was an alien cop in search of drugs
3. The setting was on a human planet (I presume Earth, but I could be wrong since I don't remember whether the humans had colonized more planets)
4. I think the main protagonist had friends on said planet

Edit: I remembered two more things

1. Drug is something we use every day, possibly coffee, sugar or tobacco
2. Alien is annoyed how cold planet is

Comment: No, this says that is very dangerous drug. If i remember correctly drug in this book was more like common substance on Earth (or whatever planet) like coffee or sugar.

Comment: Could the substance have been ginger? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worldwar_series

Comment: No we are not in war, he is just investigating drug smuggling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like [*Iceworld* by Hal Clement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iceworld):

> The novel concerns an interplanetary narcotics agent who is forced to work on **an incredibly cold world** (from his point of view — the planet is in fact Earth), where he teams up with natives of the alien planet (humans) in his attempt to stop the smuggling of **a dangerous drug (tobacco) to Sirius.** Although the story involves both aliens and humans, **it is told primarily from an alien perspective.**

Comment: You got it... One look at cover on wiki and I knew it was it. Now just yo find where to buy it :D  Thanks